# vim: replace a string with special characters with string including special characters

Tags: linux, search, vim, replace

I want to replace (multiple instances of) a string with special characters with another string which also contain special characters.

Example:

I want to replace `(path + "\\` this with `(os.path.join(path, "`

input:

`open(path + "\\filename.bin")`

output:

`open(os.path.join(path, "filename.bin"))`

I could use `/\Vopen(path + "\\\\` to search instances of these, -- This worked fine

and to replace, I tried: `%s:/\Vopen(path + "\\\\/(os.path.join(path, "/gc` but this did not work

Please help me here.

Also,
Can we have some start of marker like 'any string' (quotes) for complete string?

like we use in `grep -rni 'text-to match ( ; "' dir/` here quote `''` is used to mark start and end of string.

Comment: [vi.se] might be a better place to ask.

Comment: Can you clarify _this did not work_?  Did you mean `:%s` where you wrote `%s:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type `:%s`..., not `%s:`... . Here is the corrected line:

```
:%s/\Vopen(path + "\\\\/(os.path.join(path, "/gc
```

---

The string delimiter here is `/`:

```
:%s/\Vopen(path + "\\\\/(os.path.join(path, "/gc
   ^                   ^                     ^
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes I was using command wrongly. ```:%s/``` is correct. 
Now Replace is working fine, as I intended.

Comment: @ranjithkonaje Happy to help. If this or any other answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. To accept an answer, click the check mark button (✓) underneath the vote buttons.